# Weird colors when stacking videos

Tags: editing

I want to "stack" two (or more) videos with the same background, such that it looks like there are two people moving at the same time (not sure if stacking is the right term for that?).

So far, I've tried that using opencv-python, both by summing or averaging the overlapping frames.

The desired effect is there, but I get these weird colors:

[image]

Where do these effects come from and how can I avoid them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a case where you get an *overflow*.

Just doing an addition of two components with a char (or `std::uint8_t` in C++) will often overflow. I don't know about python implementation and how you've done your add, but just checking whether it's more than 255 if the value is on one byte is not going to work. You need to do the addition in at least a short, average, then save the results.

One way people deal with this issue is by using a float for each pixel. The addition won't break the type and you can easily calculate the average afterward.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! :)